# audioPlayer sound played on IPhone different than IPAD (Iphone is low volume and has to be held to ear)

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

I am playing a sound file in an APP and on the iPhone plays with volume like it is a phone call (you have to hold the phone to your ear).
When played on the iPad it plays like you would expect, sounds like a music file being played.
Does anyone know how to make the iPhone play a sound like it is music playing?

Here is what I use to play the sound:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/30perMinute2.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog(@"selection didn't work");
    else {
  //        [audioPlayer stop];
        [audioPlayer play];
    }
```

I have set the volume in `audioPlayer`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is whatr ended up fixing the problem:

In AppDelegate.h

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

In AppDelegate.m
In application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions add

```
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&sessionError];
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);
```